# Generic class implementing interface fails

Tags: c#

A meet a strange problem at compimation saying that a class does not implement an interface.

Lets say a v got a class:

```
public Class MyClass
{
...
}
```

And an interace:

```
public Interface IMyInterface
{
 MyClass PropertyOfMyClass {get;}
}
```

and now a generic class:

```
public class MyGeneric<T> where T:MyClass
{
  T PropertyOfMyClass 
  {
    get{return ...;}
  }
}
```

Until here everythings fine and compiles right.

But this will break at compilation time:

```
public class MyGeneric<T>:IMyInterace where T:MyClass
    {
      T PropertyOfMyClass 
      {
        get{return ...;}
      }
    }
```

Saying that MyGeneric does not implements method of IMyInterface. But obviously it does, not ?

Comment: The think that I dont understand is that if T is type or descendent of MyClass then the property T PropertyOfMyClass is equals to MyClass PropertyOfMyClass. So why does this not compile?

Answer (score 6):

You can't implement properties (or methods) from interfaces with variance. This doesn't just affect generics. For example:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    object Bar();
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    // This won't compile
    string Bar() { return "hello"; }
}
```

Now you *can* get round this with explicit interface implementation:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    // Make the interface implementation call the more strongly-typed method
    object IFoo.Bar() { return Bar(); }

    string Bar() { return "hello"; }
}
```

That may be an answer for you - or it may not. We'd need to know exactly why you wanted to declare the property as being of type `T` rather than just `MyClass` to know for sure.

Comment: I don't want to return a MyClass instance because I've got full hierarchy under My class and the generic returns me the right class without casting.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround would be to make the interface generic itself :

```
public interface IMyInterface<T> where T : MyClass
{
    T PropertyOfMyClass { get; }
}
```

You can then use it on a class :

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> : IMyInterface<T> where T : MyClass
{
    T PropertyOfMyClass 
    { 
        get { ... } 
    }
}
```

Note that using this implementation, the constraint on T in the generic class can be different from the one on the interface, as long as it ensures the interface constraint is respected :

```
public class MyOtherClass : MyClass
{
}

public class MyOtherGenericClass<T> : IMyInterface<T> where T : MyOtherClass
{
    T PropertyOfMyClass
    {
        get { ... }
    }
}
```